# How to get previous url before Symfony2 redirects to login page

Tags: symfony, authentication, uri, redirect

I configured the authentication like below:

```
pattern: ^/secured/*
form_login:
  check_path: _login_check
  login_path: _login #/login
```

That is, when I enter `http://www.example.com/secured/user`, it will redirect to `http://www.example.com/login` without any information about `/secured/user` uri.

I need to know it for using later. So, how can I get that uri?

Comment: why do you need it for later? There might be a different way you see... You can redirect back to referrer using "use_referer: true" should that be your requirement

Comment: +1 with stefancarlton, just want to add that default behaviour with Symfony authentication is that you will be redirected back to /secured/user automatically after giving correct crediential to /login

Comment: @Florent I want to add /secured/user or whatever the last redirect url on registration, so it redirects back after user sign up. right now it only works with login, but registration takes to home. do you know how we can get security last path? which login uses

Comment: Im thinking of implement the same, and now i hit the same problem. A user copy our application url link given by his colleague, and paste into his browser. only to be slap in his face that after login, it lands on the default homepage.  Any way to get previous url since this doesn't work: $this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer') ?

Comment: Anyone know this answer of this question?

Answer (score 5):

after user is logged in correctly you can rederected him to the referer url using

```
$this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer')
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to get that url before login.

Comment: how reliable is this? what if the HTTP_REFERER is not set from the browser side?

Comment: @mojo you will get redirected to the default redirection page of the config

Comment: @SofienBenrhouma thank you for the reply, any alternatives for this? here's  a question that is very similar to what i need (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649157/reliably-redirect-to-last-accessed-page-in-symfony2) its gone unanswered

Comment: I am also tried $this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer') but no values returned.