# Reliably redirect to last accessed page in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm embedding the FosUserBundle login inside my home page, i have overriddent the security controller of fos and changed the renderLogin() action, i had to put an `if` condition to redirect to last accessed page using **referers** , that *was* all well and good, but i realize now that The HTTP Referer header is not required by the HTTP Protocol and it can be compleatly skipped or even spoofed by browser setting etc. *its unreliable*!

but if symfony framework can **guarantee** `$request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER')` or `$request->headers->get('referer')` will be set. i can use these without hassle

my question to SO

- is the referer from symfony request object 100% reliable?
- what is the difference between `$request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER')` and `$request->headers->get('referer')` ?
- what could be alternatives if they are not reliable?

(P.S)

in symfony [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#redirecting-after-success)

> if the user requested http://www.example.com/admin/post/18/edit, then after they successfully log in, they will eventually be sent back to http://www.example.com/admin/post/18/edit. This is done by storing the requested URL in the session.

but they have't explained the inner working of it. if **referers** are finally proved to be unreliable then my alternatives are as below, any suggestion are welcomed

1). registering a listner and adding an attribute `last_path`

2). storing a session variable `last_path`

Comment: By default if you access secured area you will be redirected back after login success.

Comment: yes, since i'm overriding the renderLogin() and have some of my own logic that needs to know the last path, i need to know how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in security.yml

```
main:
            pattern: ^/
            logout: true
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                login_path: /login
                success_handler: authentication_handler
                failure_handler: authentication_handler
            remember_me:
                key:      secret
                lifetime: 604800
                path:     /
                domain:   yourdomain.com
            anonymous: true
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
                handler: authentication_handler
```

in the config.yml

```
services:
     authentication_handler:
       class: YourBundle\UserBundle\Security\AuthenticationHandler
```

the AuthentificationHandler Class

```
 <?PHP

    Namespace YourBundle\UserBundle\Security;

    class AuthenticationHandler implements
    AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface, AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface {

        public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
            $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
            $request->getSession()->setFlash('LoginError', $exception->getMessage());

            return new RedirectResponse($referer);
        }

        public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface $token) {
            $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
            $request->getSession()->setFlash('LoginError', "success");
            return new RedirectResponse($referer);
        }

        public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request) {
            $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
            return new RedirectResponse($referer);
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: +1 for adding yet another option to my list, but i decided to go against using referers, i guess listeners are the only way to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the URL requested before you log in session, and then if successful redirect the user to the desired URL.

The URL is captured and saved in the session start method and then recovered in onAuthenticationSuccess method.

obs .: It will be shown below only the portion of code required for understanding the solution, the code in its entirety can be accessed at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

```
<?php
namespace VER\VerCoreBundle\Security;

class FormAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
  {
    $url = $this->router->generate('_welcome');
    $previous = $request->getSession()->get('previous');

    if ($previous) {
      $url = $previous;
    }
    return new RedirectResponse($url);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
  {
    $request->getSession()->set('previous', $request->getUri());
    $url = $this->router->generate('ver_core_login');
    return new RedirectResponse($url);
  }

}
?>
```